# NodeJS Sequelize - Fetch the ID from the row just created in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

Currently, my code returns a message which says 'Registration successful'. How can I return the id of the row I just created in MySQL instead?

```
function register(req, res, next) { 
    accountService.register(req.body, req.get('origin'))
        .then(() => res.json({ message: 'Registration successful' }))
        .catch(next);
}
```

Here's the model;

```
const { DataTypes } = require('sequelize');

module.exports = model;

function model(sequelize) {
    const attributes = {
        id: {type: Sequelize.INTEGER,primaryKey:true,autoIncrement: true,allowNull: false},
        email: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
        passwordHash: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
        name: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
        gavatar: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },               
        role: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
        verificationToken: { type: DataTypes.STRING },
        verified: { type: DataTypes.DATE },
        resetToken: { type: DataTypes.STRING },
        resetTokenExpires: { type: DataTypes.DATE },
        passwordReset: { type: DataTypes.DATE },
        created: { type: DataTypes.DATE, allowNull: false, defaultValue: DataTypes.NOW },
        updated: { type: DataTypes.DATE },      
        isVerified: {
            type: DataTypes.VIRTUAL,
            get() { return !!(this.verified || this.passwordReset); }
        }
    };

    const options = {
        timestamps: false, 
        defaultScope: {
             attributes: { exclude: ['passwordHash'] }
        },
        scopes: {
            withHash: { attributes: {}, }
        }        
    };

    return sequelize.define('account', attributes, options);
}
```

I tried this;

`accountService.register(req.body,req.get('origin')).then(()=>res.json(account.id))`

But I got an error which said;

```
"message":"Cannot read property 'findOne' of undefined"
```

Here's the register function in the account.service.js;

```
async function register(params, origin) {
  
    if (await db.Account.findOne({ where: { email: params.email } })) {
        return await sendAlreadyRegisteredEmail(params.email, origin);
    }

    const account = new db.Account(params);

    const isFirstAccount = (await db.Account.count()) === 0;
    account.role = isFirstAccount ? Role.Admin : Role.User;
    account.verificationToken = randomTokenString();

    account.passwordHash = await hash(params.password);

    await account.save();
    
    await sendVerificationEmail(account, origin);
  }
```

I'm not sure where to find the id.

Comment: What does your `accountService.register` method do? Could you please post it?

Comment: Usually, based on [Sequelize docs](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-create) the `Model.create` method should return the created ID as `result.id` without need to run a `.findOne` after. That should be located inside the `account.service` file, as the `register` function

Comment: Ok. I've just edited and added the "register" function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on your updated code your `.register` function is actually returning nothing. What you should do is update that function making it return the new created ID, or the already existing ID (if you need it).

```
accountService.register(req.body, req.get('origin'))
    .then(() => res.json(account.id));
```

This part of code you already tested doesn't work because of `account` missing inside the `.then` promise resolution. Also, as your method does not return anything, you won't be able to access anything inside the `.then(() => {})` callback.

You could try updating the `register` function as following

```
async function register(params, origin) {
  const existingAccount = await db.Account.findOne({
      where: { email: params.email }
  });
  if (existingAccount) {
    await sendAlreadyRegisteredEmail(params.email, origin);
    return existingAccount.id;
  }

  const isFirstAccount = (await db.Account.count()) === 0;

  const accountParams = {
    ...params,
    role: isFirstAccount ? Role.Admin : Role.User,
    verificationToken: randomTokenString(),
    passwordHash: await hash(params.password)
  }
  
  const account = await db.Account.create(
    accountParams, { isNewRecord: true }
  );

  await sendVerificationEmail(account, origin);
  
  return account.id;
}
```

And update your API handler as following

```
accountService.register(req.body, req.get('origin'))
    .then((id) => res.json({id}))
```

Please note that if `params.password` is present, you are currently saving Account password both hashed and cleartext, which should be avoided

Comment: What should I do with this?    accountService.register(req.body, req.get('origin')).then(() => res.json(account.id )).catch(next);

Comment: @Meggy please have a look at my updated answer

Comment: Unfortunately I'm getting the same error: {"message":"Cannot read property 'findOne' of undefined"}

Comment: @Meggy this issue is related to how are you importing your models. `db.Accounts.findOne` assumes that both `db` and `db.Accounts` exist, which does not seems the case

Comment: Scratch that last comment. It works! Once I removed the line " id: {type: Sequelize.INTEGER,primaryKey:true,autoIncrement: true,allowNull: false},
        " on models.js it started working.